# Formatting a parameter in an input statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to format a parameter in an input statement (if there is a way).
For example:

```
scoring_choice = input("If you want to reroll, enter REROLL\n"
                       "If you want to score, enter to which category?\n> ")
if scoring_choice.lower() == f'reroll {x}':
    player1 = reroll(player1, x)
```

referring to the function:

```
def reroll(player, x)
    if x.lower() == 'all':
        player = player.reroll()
        print(player)
    else:
        try:
            if int(x) in range(1, 7):
                player[int(x)-1] = random.randint(1, 6)
                print(player)
        except ValueError:
            print("Oops, please choosing a valid option")
    return player, x
```

I am wondering how to do this the correct way if there is one.
Like how to add an if statement to the parameter.

Sorry if I am using wrong terms or words. 
And I know the syntax of this piece of code doesn't make any sense, but I edited the original one which does work with this one to make an example of what I mean.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I can't see any `input` calls in your code.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you want to get the `{x}` in `'reroll {x}'`?

Comment: Please improve the example and description of your problem. We'd like to see a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The question is still unclear. Describe step by step what you want to do.

Comment: Write @skrx if/when you update the question to contact me.